# Why does British English use "Collective are" and others use "Collective is"?

Tags: british-english

Since Indian English uses "Collective is" I feel British English has adopted it after the colonial days. When did countries diverge on is/are and which countries use the British system?

Comment: No, British English uses the non-rhotic "are".

Comment: I don't think you can assume that current Indian English reflects the British English of the colonial era. I'd be surprised if collective *are* was that recent, because *is* - or rather the singular - always sounds wrong to me in sentences like *Manchester United fails to qualify for next season's Champions League*, and I think I'd have noticed if 19th century writers used that construction.

Comment: Also, if AmE allows it that suggests it was in use by the time of American independence...